# How to prove an inequality involving logarithm

Tags: inequality, logarithms

It is a high school problem my friend asked me.I want to show that for all $0\leq x,y<1$, we have the following inequality:
$$(1-y^2)x^2\log(1-y^2)+(1-x^2)y^2\log(1-x^2)\geq 2xy(1-xy)\log(1-xy).$$
It looks symmetric and beautiful on its own and quite strict. I plotted by Mathematica and realized so far that the equality happens when $x=y$ or $x.y=0$. I am not used to inequalities involving logarithms, so if someone can give me some techniques or any methods would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Divide the inequality by $x^2y^2$ to see that it can be written as 
$$
 f(xy) \le \frac 12 \left( f(x^2) + f(y^2) \right)
$$
where $f$ is defined on $ (0, 1)$ as $f(t) = \frac{(1-t)\log(1-t)}{t}$.

With the substitution $x^2 = e^u$, $y^2 = e^v$ this is equivalent to
$$
 f(e^{(u+v)/2}) \le \frac 12 \left(f(e^u) + f(e^v) \right)
$$
for $u, v < 0$, so that it suffices to show that
$$
 g(u) = f(e^u) = (e^{-u} -1) \log(1-e^u)
$$
is a *convex* function on $(-\infty, 0)$. This can be verified by computing the second derivative.

Spoiler:

> $$ g''(u) = e^{-u} \log(1-e^u) + \frac{1}{1-e^u} \ge 0 $$ because of the “well-known” inequality $$ \log(1+x) \ge \frac{x}{1+x} \quad \text{for } x > -1 \, . $$

Comment: @Dynamic: I don't know. – Btw, it seems that your edit was not sufficient to prevent your question from being closed. We can try to reopen it, but it would be helpful if you try to improve the question further. One option would be to add the Mathematic plots that you have.